# Regex to remove !IMAGE and strings in between [] bracket

Tags: regex

Regex replace text but exclude tag !IMAGE and strings in between [] bracket and any png strings inside the sentence and retain only the strings in between ""

I have the following string: !IMAGE[lod resources tab.png](lod resources tab.png "Screenshot of Resources tab in the lab interface")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in javascript

```js
const str = `!IMAGE[lod resources tab.png](lod resources tab.png "Screenshot of Resources tab in the lab interface")`;

const regex = new RegExp(/"([\w ]+)"/);
const match = str.match(regex)
console.log(match[1])
```

The parenthesis in the regex allows to create a group, in this group we only have the part inside the quotes.

- `\w`: A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.
- `[\w ]+` Selects 1 or more word characters or space characters.